# What is probability that out of the first half on N objects, none will be matched with their own label?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations, inclusion-exclusion

The problem: We have N (even) objects ordered $o_1 ... o_N$ , each having their own label. The labels are reassigned to the objects randomly. What is the probability that that neither of the first $N/2$ objects ($o_1 ... o_{N/2}$) are matched with their own label?

---

My attempt: We use the inclusion-exclusion principle:

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right) = \sum_{k=1}^n\left((-1)^{k-1}\sum_{I\subset\{1,...,n\} ; |I|=k} \mathbb{P}(A_I)\right  )$$

We let $A_i$ denote the event that object $i$ get's matched with its own label. Then

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{N/2} A_i\right)$$

is the probability that at least one of the first half of the objects gets a match and

$$1 - \mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{N/2} A_i\right)$$

is the probability that none of the first half get a match, which is the result we want.

Now for the probability of any combination of $n$ matches from the first half of the objects we have:

$$\sum_{(i_1,...,i_k):1\leq i_1 \leq ... \leq i_k \leq N/2} \mathbb{P}(A_{i_1}\cap ...\cap A_{i_k})$$

And we want to rewrite this using factorial notation:

We have

$$\frac{(N/2)!}{n!(N/2-n)!}$$

possible combinations of matches. For each of those, the probability that that arrangement will happen is $$\frac{(N-n)!}{N!}$$

so we can say:

$$\sum_{(i_1,...,i_k):1\leq i_1 \leq ... \leq i_k \leq N/2} \mathbb{P}(A_{i_1}\cap ...\cap A_{i_k}) = \frac{(N/2)!}{n!(N/2-n)!} \times \frac{(N-n)!}{N!}$$

and then our final answer would be:

$$1 - \sum_{n=1}^{N/2}\left((-1)^{n-1} \frac{(N/2)!}{n!(N/2-n)!} \times \frac{(N-n)!}{N!} \right)$$

Does this make sense? Is there any easier way of solving this?

Comment: For large (and even modest) $N$, this is approximately the value of the Poisson distribution of mean $\frac{1}{2}$ at zero, namely $\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}} = 0.60653\!\ldots$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution

Comment: @Travis I tried it in wolframalpha for N=2000 and got 0.606493. Should I take it as an indication that my answer is correct?

Comment: Agreement to four decimal places is certainly strong evidence.

Comment: You can use `\ldots` instead of `...` to get the right spacing.

Answer (score 1):

This makes a lot of sense, and I doubt that there's a significantly easier way of solving this. You basically followed the usual derivation of the number of derangements, and the result in that case, where there's greater symmetry, can't be simplified, so it would be surprising if it could be simplified in this case. The only simplification I see is that you could include $n=0$ in the sum instead of writing the $1$ separately; your result is actually

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N/2}(-1)^n\frac{(N/2)!(N-n)!}{n!(N/2-n)!N!}\;.
$$

Comment: Do you have an extra factor here or am I misreading things?

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: The extra factor $\frac1{N!}$ is there because the question asked for the probability and you gave the count instead; other than that the results are identical.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic scenario where  the underlying poset has the subsets
of $[m]$ (where $n/2=m$) as nodes,  order is by set inclusion, and the
Mobius function on the nodes is the usual $(-1)^q$ with $q$ the number
of elements.   Therefore we can  just plug  these data into  the usual
inclusion-exclusion formula to get

$$\sum_{q=0}^m {m\choose q} (-1)^q (2m-q)!$$

which is the sequence

$$1, 14, 426, 24024, 2170680, 287250480,
\\ 52370755920, 12585067447680,\ldots$$

which is [OEIS A033815](https://oeis.org/A033815).

Now this  is a  very simple problem  but just in  case we  have any
sceptics  remaining  here  is  a  script  to  help  verify  the  above
computation.

```
with(combinat);

Q :=
proc(m)
local res, perm, pos;
option remember;

    res := 0;

    perm := firstperm(2*m);

    while type(perm, `list`) do
        for pos to m do
            if perm[pos] = pos then
                break
            fi;
        od;

        if pos = m + 1 then
            res := res + 1
        fi;

        perm := nextperm(perm);
    od;

    res
end;

T := m -> add(binomial(m,q)*(-1)^q*(2*m-q)!, q=0..m);
```

Comment: Thanks; I wasn't aware of this connection between Möbius inversion and inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: It is a useful exercise and might help the OP in understanding to draw the poset and the Mobius function for the case of set inclusion (case A, size zero is wanted, case B, size $m$ is wanted) and in the case of the divisor poset, where we get the Mobius function from number theory.